# Error - "Please use BI Publisher desktop installer 32 bit" but Office is 64 bit

Tags: microsoft-word, installation

I have 64-bit editions of Windows and Office, but everytime I try to install BI Publisher 64-bit on my PC, I am getting this error "Please use BI Publisher desktop installer 32 bit".

However, when I install the 32-bit installer of BI Publisher, the add-ins of BI Pubsliher don't show up in Word. I tried all the suggestion from Google but I can't fix this error. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: "I tried all the suggestion from Google" - You need to be specific about which solutions you attempted.  Your 64-bit Office installation will be unable to use a 32-bit add-on.  You have not indicated which version of Office you have installed.  You have not identified which version of the BI Publisher you have installed.  All this information is required to answer your question.  Please edit your question to provide this vital required information.

Comment: OH sorry. I tried to install Bi Publisher 32 bit because when I installed Bi Publisher 64 bit I getting this error "Please use BI Publisher desktop installer 32 bit". My Office is 64 bit and my windows is 64 bit. My Java version is Java 8u181.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide enough information so your question can be answered

Answer (score 0):

When running the 64-bit installer you need to **Run as Administrator**.

*Source*: My anecdotal frustrating experience of installing the 64-bit, getting the "Please use BI Publisher desktop installer 32-bit" message, installing the 32-bit, getting a "menu2007..." issue, uninstalling everything, installing the 64-bit with "Run as Administrator", and then everything working.

Comment: Hi. The message "Please use BI Publisher desktop installer 32-bit" show again while installing the 64 bit. Can you give me another suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Did you completely uninstall your previous BI Pub Desktop installations?

Comment: (Accidentally submitted previous comment too soon, and tried to edit too late....)

Please also clarify: You right-clicked on the _BIPublisherDesktop64.exe_ file and chose **Run as Administrator**?